# Problem with SDF files or robot_description parameter

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I am working my way through some of the tutorials for ROS/Gazebo. I am running into some issues with the [ROS Control with Gazebo Tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo) however. In particular when I launch the robot_control package, I get an error saying

```
Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server
```

After a little digging I added the following to my launch file:

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="path/to/robot.sdf"/>
```

to set the robot_description parameter. However after I did that I get the error:

```
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher
[ERROR] [1376891403.184690567]: Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
[ERROR] [1376891403.184756779]: Could not generate robot model
[ERROR] [1376891403.184774430]: Failed to extract kdl tree from xml robot description
```

So I am guessing that what is happening is that robot_state_publisher is looking for a URDF file while I am providing a SDF file. How do I get around this?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4192/problem-with-sdf-files-or-robot_description-parameter/) by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi munnveed,

I had the same problem. If you want to use RVIZ with gazebo, you definetly need an urdf-description of your robot. My workaroud was, to have both, an URDF model for the robot_description, and an SDF model for the visualization.

But this was very difficult to maintain, since all changes had to be done in both models. In the meanwhile, I took the time to setup an URDF model and extended this with  elements as evilBiber already explained. Gazebo is able to convert it on loading, but i has to be without mistakes, otherwise the parser will fail.

regards

psei

---

Originally posted by [psei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/464/psei/) with karma: 166 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

if you are working with ros it might be better to change your SDFs to URDFs otherwise you won't be able to use some ROS specific things like RVIZ or the RobotStatePublisher for your robot which might be essential!

URDFs can handle all gazebo specific things inside a `<gazebo>` element.

I know no reason not to use URDFs when you are working with ROS (if there is please let me know...)

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/457/munnveed/) on 2013-08-19**:
Ok, thank you. The only reason I was using SDF is because I was following the Gazebo tutorials, which uses SDF and suggests that SDF is a superior format ("the Simulator Description Format (SDF) was created for use in Gazebo to solve the shortcomings of URDF"). I did not realize that the robot description file would be needed by ROS as well, and that ROS does not use SDF.  Thank you for the clarification.

**Comment by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/240/hououin-kyouma/) on 2013-11-06**:
I created a URDF model in RVIZ first and it worked fine there, but somehow it didn't work in Gazebo.. In Gazebo all links were omitted except for the base link (in my case). So I created a seperate SDF file which does work in Gazebo, but like you said yourself, that's not ideal in ROS either.. So I wished that URDF was as compatible with Gazebo as everyone claims, but I actually have my doubts about that, seeing that I can't even load a URDF model properly in Gazebo. That's why I use SDF now..

**Comment by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/240/hououin-kyouma/) on 2013-11-06**:
Never mind, I humbly take back my words. Somehow, the URDF file is working now in Gazebo, which means I can use ros_control in its whole as well.